# timestampz column not queryable in function

Tags: postgresql

I have a function call like :

```
SELECT * FROM f_loop_in_lockstep_final('{454,454}'::int[]
                             , '{2,3}'::int[], to_date('2023-01-17','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I have declared funtion as :

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION f_loop_in_lockstep_final(_id_arr int[], _counter_arr int[], d_date date)
```

In the function body I have written the following where clause (simplified):

```
select * from routes where

    routes.time_created between ((d_date::date + '11:59:00'::time) at time zone '+05:00') and ((d_date::date + '18:00:00'::time) at time zone '+05:00')
```

This is giving a null result set (although no errors are displayed), whereas I know for sure that it should be non null result set.

P.S - Here is the simplified code of my function:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION f_loop_in_lockstep_final(_id_arr int[], _counter_arr int[], d_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (uc_name_ varchar)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  
$func$
DECLARE
   _id int;
   _counter int;
  d_date date; 
BEGIN
   FOR _id, _counter IN 
      SELECT *
      FROM   unnest (_id_arr, _counter_arr) t  
   LOOP
   
   
   
   RETURN QUERY

      

with orig_dataset as (

select routes
from campaign_routes cr  
where cr.created_at between ((d_date::date + '11:59:00'::time) at time zone '+05:00') and ((d_date::date + '18:00:00'::time) at time zone '+05:00')
)


-- a couple of further CTE's result in a final CTE called final_cte

select * from final_cte;


END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Comment: Some sample data to reproduce the problem would help to clear that up. Without that, all I can say is "you know for sure, but the database knows for surer".

Comment: shoud I provide my function? or target table details? please let me know, I am so confused.

Comment: routes.time_created is a timestamptz column

Comment: routes.time_created has data in the form of "2022-12-04 07:22:42.000 +0500"

Comment: Edit the question and add a `CREATE TABLE` statement and a couple of `INSERT`s so that we can reproduce what you are experiencing.

Comment: Why don't you post the code of this function? We can now only guess what bug could be there.

Comment: the code of the function is quite long

Comment: Well, maybe that's the reason why a bug got there in the first place... I always try to stay below 50 lines of code, works for me.

Comment: I have provided a simplified version of it. When I hardcode the date value, the code works.

Comment: 1) This `to_date('2023-01-17','YYYY-MM-DD')` can be simplified to `'2023-01-17'::date`.  The result of `to_date` is going to be presented in whatever format is set by `DateStyle` anyway same as the simplified version. 2) Does `at time zone '+05:00'` represent the `timezone` offset for the server? If so then simplify to `(d_date::date + '11:59:00'::time)::timestamptz`. If not what is the server `timezone` setting?

Comment: the timezone works thanks! there is probably some other bug which I am trying to figure out